# blocked Instagram Application or Account?

Tags: instagram

Everytime I try to authorize this instagram application I get this error.:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request.

I'm not sure if it is a default error because Instagram is working on something or if it is an error because of the client / account. And if I try to open http://instagram.com/developer also an error occurs.

Could someone of you try to authorize this application? (I am not going to save any data.)

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=9e262d946e4f4d9987885588669e8b4f&redirect_uri=http://www.netstagram.com/oauth2callback&response_type=token&amp

Please report if it worked or not.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem currently.  I'm pretty sure the instagram API is down right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram's API is currently down and offline. Every application I've tested (as well as my own) doesn't work.  I keep getting for 502 gateway error.

They should probably fix the problem on Monday.